# unable to run the karate scripts for API intigration test when I run TestRunner.java

Tags: java, api, karate, spring-boot-test

I am trying to execute all my feature files to test the APIs end to end, but when I run the TestRunner.java file as JUnit, nothing happens in my eclipse.

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import com.intuit.karate.junit4.Karate;
@RunWith(Karate.class)
 public class TestRunner {}
```

and Here is my feature file

```
Feature: fetching User Details
 Scenario: testing the get call for Employee Details
 Given url 'http://localhost:9091/getAllEmployees'
 When method GET
 Then status 200
```

I have below dependency in my pom

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
        <artifactId>karate-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
      <dependency>
              <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
              <artifactId>karate-apache</artifactId>
              <version>0.9.6</version>
              <scope>test</scope>
       </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
        <artifactId>karate-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

and created my own profile to just run only end to end script

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>e2e</id>
         <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <includes>
                            <include>TestRunner.java</include>
                        </includes>
                        <groups>com.inmemory.h2.employee.karate</groups>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                <goal>verify</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

when I run mvn verify -Pe2e , Nothing happens, It is not generating any report . also If I run TestRunner.java nothing happens

[image]

[image]

Kindly suggest what I am doing wrong here

Comment: my personal opinion is sorry, follow this process else no one can help: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Thank you Peter, I tried all the online help but no luck.

Comment: you are mixing old and wrong versions of karate, I have reasons for asking you to do the above process, at least locally. all the best

Comment: @KishoreJetty Are the TestRunner & Feature files in the same package? If Yes, Test Runner should pick the feature files by default. Otherwise, you need to pass the feature files locations using @KarateOptions(features = location of feature files) (which is deprecated).

Comment: Thank you @PeterThomas . Yes you are right . I am using Junit5 and my local tests are working fine now. Thank you very much for this page again

Comment: Yes Srini, I am having all features in same package

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that TestRunner.java and yourfile.feature are in the same package src/test/java/yourPackage/

also add this to your pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>src/test/java</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>
</build>
```